# Changing the default kernel does not change uname

Tags: kernel, wireguard, centos-8

I have a hetzner server, and I wanted to use wireguard on the server. As shown below, my wireguard module is only available for the kernel version "4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64".

```
$ rpm -ql kmod-wireguard
    /etc/depmod.d/kmod-wireguard.conf
    /lib/modules/4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64
    /lib/modules/4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64/extra
    /lib/modules/4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64/extra/wireguard
    /lib/modules/4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64/extra/wireguard/wireguard.ko
    /usr/share/doc/kmod-wireguard-1.0.20211208
    /usr/share/doc/kmod-wireguard-1.0.20211208/GPL-v2.0.txt
    /usr/share/doc/kmod-wireguard-1.0.20211208/greylist.txt
```

But my default kernel is "4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64".

```
$ uname -r
    4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64
```

Due to this, I am unable to load the wireguard module. So I used grubby to change to a different version using,

```
$ sudo grubby --info=ALL
    index=0
    kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-365.el8.x86_64"
    args="ro no_timer_check net.ifnames=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet $tuned_params"
    root="UUID=7f43b423-ee85-4c1d-a417-41c68e8a8b40"
    initrd="/boot/initramfs-4.18.0-365.el8.x86_64.img $tuned_initrd"
    title="CentOS Stream (4.18.0-365.el8.x86_64) 8"
    id="78424947c1b94df5bc577331dc9da098-4.18.0-365.el8.x86_64"
    index=1
    kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-78424947c1b94df5bc577331dc9da098"
    args="ro no_timer_check net.ifnames=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
    root="UUID=7f43b423-ee85-4c1d-a417-41c68e8a8b40"
    initrd="/boot/initramfs-0-rescue-78424947c1b94df5bc577331dc9da098.img"
    title="CentOS Stream (0-rescue-78424947c1b94df5bc577331dc9da098) 8"
    id="78424947c1b94df5bc577331dc9da098-0-rescue"
    index=2
    kernel="/boot/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64"
    args="ro no_timer_check net.ifnames=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet $tuned_params"
    root="UUID=7f43b423-ee85-4c1d-a417-41c68e8a8b40"
    initrd="/boot/boot/initramfs-4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64.img $tuned_initrd"
    title="CentOS Linux (4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64) 8"
    id="7345eea605f14507b00f718a0027f23c-4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64"
    index=3
    kernel="/boot/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-7345eea605f14507b00f718a0027f23c"
    args="ro no_timer_check net.ifnames=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
    root="UUID=7f43b423-ee85-4c1d-a417-41c68e8a8b40"
    initrd="/boot/boot/initramfs-0-rescue-7345eea605f14507b00f718a0027f23c.img"
    title="CentOS Linux (0-rescue-7345eea605f14507b00f718a0027f23c) 8"
    id="7345eea605f14507b00f718a0027f23c-0-rescue"
    index=4
    kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64"
    args="ro no_timer_check net.ifnames=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet $tuned_params"
    root="UUID=7f43b423-ee85-4c1d-a417-41c68e8a8b40"
    initrd="/boot/initramfs-4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64.img $tuned_initrd"
    title="CentOS Stream (4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64) 8"
    id="5ac25cd9d1bc40c78c39fd3edc9a219b-4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64"
    index=5
    kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-5ac25cd9d1bc40c78c39fd3edc9a219b"
    args="ro no_timer_check net.ifnames=0 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
    root="UUID=7f43b423-ee85-4c1d-a417-41c68e8a8b40"
    initrd="/boot/initramfs-0-rescue-5ac25cd9d1bc40c78c39fd3edc9a219b.img"
    title="CentOS Stream (0-rescue-5ac25cd9d1bc40c78c39fd3edc9a219b) 8"
    id="5ac25cd9d1bc40c78c39fd3edc9a219b-0-rescue"
$ sudo grubby --set-default-index=4
    The default is /boot/loader/entries/5ac25cd9d1bc40c78c39fd3edc9a219b-4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64.conf with index 4 and kernel /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64
```

And after rebooting, I still did not see any change in the uname results, it still stayed as "4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64". I also saw that the title of this kernel is CentOS Linux 8 and not stream, but checking the centos release file shows that I am using CentOS Stream 8.

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
    CentOS Stream release 8
```

Can someone please tell me how to switch the kernel? Thank you.

Comment: Usually the wireguard dkms should work on kernels as old as 3.10. Are you absolutely sure the problem is the kernel itself?

Comment: Based on your question, to double-check, I reinstalled wireguard tools and kmodwireguard and it resolved the problem. Not really sure why, as the folder location did not change. Maybe the binary files were corrupted. Thank you for your help.